# Java Add Click Listener to JButton in Loop in Thread

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, bufferedimage

I have a loop, in which several JLabel's are created, containing a link to an image.

For each JLabel, there is a JButton created.

The behaviour I'm looking for is that for each JButton, to add a click listener, which fires a method.

The first issue is that it seems as though I am unable to add a Listener within the thread.

The second issue is that I don't see how I can specify each JButton to fire the click listener with a different value.

I'm looking for something similar to the following (obviously onClick method doesn't exist):

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        for (int counter = 0; counter < imageSources.size(); counter++)
        {
            JLabel imageSource = imageSources.get(counter);
            // JButton saveToDisk = new JButton("Save Image");
            // saveToDisk.onClick(saveFavourite(imageSources.get(counter)));
            mainPanel.add(imageSource);
            // mainPanel.add(saveToDisk);
        }

.
.
.

public void saveFavourite(String imageUrl)
{
    BufferedImage image = null;
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
        image = ImageIO.read(url);
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/" + webPage.getMemeId(imageUrl) + ".jpg"));
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: This confuses me: `"The behaviour I'm looking for is that for each JButton, to add a click listener, which fires a method."` -- Can you explain in greater detail what this means and what you're trying to do.

Comment: In a loop, I am creating several JButtons, I want each JButton to have an on-click listener, which executed a method.

Comment: Also, are you trying to create and add Swing components off of the EDT, the Swing event dispatch thread? If so, don't.

Comment: JButton's use ActionListeners not "on-click listeners". If you add an ActionListener to the button, or set its Action, then this should take care of things for you.

Comment: I've heard of this before, are you referring to InvokeLater? Should I replace Runnable with InvokeLater? But setting the JButton's action is just a string, how can I pass a value with the ActionListener?

Comment: If you need to use a background thread, then consider using a SwingWorker. Its publish/process method pair will allow the SwingWorker to publish interim results to the GUI on the Swing event thread. Check the [concurrency in Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more on this.

Comment: Thanks I will, regarding passing a value with the ActionListener, how is this possible? Is it possible to define the ActionEvent on the fly within the loop?

Comment: You need to create a class that either implements ActionListener or extends AbstractAction, give the class a constructor that takes your String of interest (or any other information that needs to be passed in), and then add that to the JButton as its ActionListener or as its Action.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17422/discussion-between-cristian-and-hovercraft-full-of-eels)

Comment: Cannot chat as I'm at work and chat is blocked by a firewall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple example of creating buttons and adding to them ActionListeners that take String arguments during a loop

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    private final JLabel[] label = new JLabel[5];
    private final JButton[] button = new JButton[5];

    public Test() {
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,2));
        for (int counter = 0; counter < label.length; counter++) {
            label[counter] = new JLabel("Label " + counter);
            button[counter] = new JButton("Button " + counter);
            button[counter].addActionListener(new MyActionListener("Row " + counter));
            mainPanel.add(label[counter]);
            mainPanel.add(button[counter]);
        }
        this.add(mainPanel);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Test run = new Test();
                run.pack();
                run.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                run.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {

        String text;

        public MyActionListener(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println(text);
        }
    }
}
```